# How can I add the same header/cookie to all JAX-RS responses?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I want to add cookies to all JAX-RS responses produced in the application. How can I do this? I don't use `Response` class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use interceptors:  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-Filters%2CInterceptorsandInvokers

probably you will be needed to write your own (extend it from some existing default output interceptor) if there is no ready-for-use solution

Comment: This feature is available only in Apache CXF an is not JAX-RS compatible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HTTPFilter that adds the cookie value to your requests. If not that then you can get hold of the context in your methods and manually handle the cookie handling

```
public Response updateCustomer(@Context HttpHeaders h, Customer c) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jersey has a concept of container filters you can use for this. In this particular case you can implement a ContainerResponseFilter that adds the cookie to the header. See the documentation on how to create and register container filters here: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/package-summary.html

Comment: This mechanism is not JAX-RS compliant, it's just a Jersey-specific trick, right?

Comment: Right. There is no notion of filters in JAX-RS 1.1. This is what we are adding in JAX-RS 2.0. If you want to be impl-independent, you can do this using a servlet filter that you map to the same URI pattern as your JAX-RS app. But that does not give you access to the internal JAX-RS objects, such as UriInfo or similar - i.e. you'll have to figure out how to pass info from your JAX-RS app to the filter if you need that.